# css Ellipsis, event on 3 dots hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, ellipsis

I have a little question, i have too long text in my cell in table in html, so i use text-overflow property set on ellipsis in css like in this example from w3c: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow
and I wonder if I can make for example that popup will show up after hover on that 3 dots on the end of text, is that possible without complicated js code? Or i have to make my own piece of code that will show 3 dots instead of rest of text and then attach on hover function to them or something ?

Comment: Try setting title attribute of element with full content. Now whenever you will hover over text a tooltip will be shown with complete text.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `title` attribute of element to achieve your objective without writing any extra code. Just run following snippet and hover over the text to see the result.

```css
.ellipses {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellipses" title="This is some long text that will not fit in the box">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, I saw solutions like that, but i meant i want to show some popup or tooltip on hovering only over that 3 dots at the end of text, not over the whole div, have You solution for that too ?:)

Comment: For that you have to rely on JS and write your own solution.

Comment: Just as i thought. I had to ask so now I'm sure i will not miss any solution. Thank You